# broadcast receiver with multiple audio events

Tags: android

I have a receiver that listens for headset MEDIA_PAUSE_PLAY and for AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY they work fine if only one is called.  But some Ford Sync systems will send a play/pause command when turning off the car.  So this then has 2 receivers active at the same time and it causes a force close because I am stopping the media player in either situation.  I have tried using a boolean but from what I have read the on receive gets killed after each event so the boolean value never gets used.  So how can I ignore the audio becoming noisy if the media play pause is received at the same time?  Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:
    package com.joebutt.mouseworldradio;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

{
//I created stopCounter to try and keep this from running more than 1 time
int stopCounter = 0;
//I created mediaAction to try and keep both receivers from activating
boolean mediaAction = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //boolean mediaAction = false;
    //int stopCounter = 0;

    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        mediaAction = true;
        //stopCounter = 1;
        if (stopCounter < 1)
        {
            //mediaAction = true; force closes here to
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE == event.getKeyCode())
            {
                stopCounter = 1;
                //mediaAction only works here if you hit the stop button 1 time, then it will work the next time you shut the car off
                mediaAction = true; 
                //stop and release the media player
                if (Play.mp.isPlaying())
                {
                Play playService = new Play();
                playService.stopPlaying();

                //stop the play service
                Intent stopPlayingService = new Intent(context, Play.class);
                context.stopService(stopPlayingService);
                //switch back to the main screen
                Intent showMain = new Intent(context, MouseWorldRadioActivity.class);
                showMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(showMain);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (!mediaAction)
    {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            if (Play.mp.isPlaying())
            {
            //stop and release the mediaplayer
            Play playService = new Play();
            playService.stopPlaying();
            //}
            //stop the play service
            Intent stopPlayingService = new Intent(context, Play.class);
            context.stopService(stopPlayingService);
            //switch back to the main screen
            Intent showMain = new Intent(context, MouseWorldRadioActivity.class);
            showMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(showMain);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my method to stop the playback:
    public void stopPlaying()
    {
        if (mp.isPlaying())
        {
            //stop playback and release everything
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(null);
            mp.setOnErrorListener(null);
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I checked to see if the media player was null for the audio becoming noisy listener.  This prevented it from trying to stop a media player that no longer existed.  Now it works great with my sync system.

Answer (score 1):

It should be okay to have two receivers active at the same time.  If the issue is that you are trying to stop the media player when it is already stopped try this in your receiver:

```
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }
```

That way you only stop the media player if it is playing.  If that's not the case, can you post code so we can see exactly what you're trying.

Comment: Nick, Thanks for the response.  I have already tried that.  I will post my code: